# Magento v1 to v2 Migration with SQLSTATE[HY093] for catalog_product_bundle_option_value

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento2-migration-tool

I've been struggling with the migration of v1.9.2.4 to v2.2.6 for a couple of days now where the settings migrate fine but when it comes to the data I get the following error and no matter what I do it doesn't pass it:

```
[2018-09-29 18:17:51][DEBUG][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Map Step][table: catalog_product_bundle_option_value]: migrating
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens


Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/vhosts/www.jawikw.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/ResourceModel/Adapter/Mysql.php:169
 PDOStatement->execute() at /var/www/vhosts/www.jawikw.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/ResourceModel/Adapter/Mysql.php:169
 Migration\ResourceModel\Adapter\Mysql->insertMultiple() at /var/www/vhosts/www.jawikw.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/ResourceModel/Adapter/Mysql.php:137
 Migration\ResourceModel\Adapter\Mysql->insertRecords() at /var/www/vhosts/www.jawikw.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/ResourceModel/Destination.php:52
 Migration\ResourceModel\Destination->saveRecords() at /var/www/vhosts/www.jawikw.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Map/Data.php:175
 Migration\Step\Map\Data->perform() at /var/www/vhosts/www.jawikw.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Mode/AbstractMode.php:79
 Migration\Mode\AbstractMode->runStage() at /var/www/vhosts/www.jawikw.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Mode/Data.php:119
 Migration\Mode\Data->runData() at /var/www/vhosts/www.jawikw.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Mode/Data.php:69
 Migration\Mode\Data->run() at /var/www/vhosts/www.jawikw.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Console/MigrateDataCommand.php:51
 Migration\Console\MigrateDataCommand->execute() at /var/www/vhosts/www.jawikw.com/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:241
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/vhosts/www.jawikw.com/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:843
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/vhosts/www.jawikw.com/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:193
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/vhosts/www.jawikw.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:104
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /var/www/vhosts/www.jawikw.com/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/vhosts/www.jawikw.com/httpdocs/bin/magento:23

migrate:data [-r|--reset] [-a|--auto] [--] <config>
```

Does anyone have any idea on what can be done to solve the issue with catalog_product_bundle_option_value?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For those having the same issue, this helped me out:

```
SELECT catalog_product_bundle_option_value.option_id FROM catalog_product_bundle_option_value LEFT JOIN catalog_product_bundle_option ON catalog_product_bundle_option_value.option_id=catalog_product_bundle_option.option_id WHERE catalog_product_bundle_option.option_id IS NULL;
```

Then delete the orphaned records from catalog_product_bundle_option_value having the same option_id.